# How to pass XMl String visualforce page to apex class

Tags: xml, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I developed a String XML type and i just want to pass these XML String to Apex class and i want to iterate the values and i need to display .please share some example

Answer (score 1):

Anil,

Look at [this example](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/parsing-xml-using-the-apex-dom-parser) on Developer Force. It should be your first point of call for any Salesforce search.

Paul